# Implement recursive onClick event in react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, recursion, textbox

I am trying to implement a recursive method on reactjs, but only when data is submitted or clicked.

Following is the code I am trying with:

```js
import React, { Component } from "react";

class Textbox extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state = {value: ''};
      this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
      this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
    }
  
    handleChange(event) {this.setState({value: event.target.value});  }
    handleSubmit(event) {
      alert('A name was submitted: ' + this.state.value);
      event.preventDefault();
    }
  
    render() {
      return (
        <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
        <div> 
          <label>
            Name:
            <input type="text" value={this.state.value} onChange={this.handleChange} />
          </label>
          <input type="submit" value="React" />
        </div> 
        </form>
      );
    }
  }

export default Textbox;
```

which generates the following view.

[image: A simple text box view]

I want to use a recursive method onClick or onSubmit, such that it will generate another text box upon submission. Like

[image: View of the new text box after the first submission.]

which I want to continue until I click some "Exit" or "Stop" button, which I can add to the top of the view.

From what I have read about recursive implementation on ReactJS, I need to call the class/function again inside render. When I do that I think react is getting inside the infinite loop and freezes the browser.

what I tried is to call `Textbox` inside the `<div> <div/>` of the render method. Like this:

```
.... other code lines are same
<div> 
  <label>
    Name:
    <input type="text" value={this.state.value} onChange={this.handleChange} />
  </label>
  <input type="submit" value="React" />
  <Textbox/>
</div>
```

How can I generate a recursive textbox on submission/clicking event on the previous text box?

Comment: A recursive function requires a stopping case. What is your stopping case?

Comment: You can have an array which keeps mapping the text area - https://codesandbox.io/s/workspace-react-z9tok?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 1):

You could do it like this, where `showNextInput` prevents the infinite loop:

```
class Textbox extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            value: '',
            showNextInput: false,
        };
        this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
        this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
    }

    handleChange(event) {this.setState({value: event.target.value});  }
    handleSubmit(event) {
        console.log('submit');
        event.preventDefault();
        this.setState({ showNextInput: true });
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <>
                <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                    <div>
                        <label>
                            Name:
                            <input type="text" value={this.state.value} onChange={this.handleChange} />
                        </label>
                        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
                    </div>
                </form>
                { this.state.showNextInput ? <Textbox/> : null }
            </>
        );
    }
}
```

However, your use case looks like something you would usually do by

- managing a list of values somewhere,
- add items as required inside your handlers, and
- then display a list of these items

Here a quick and dirty example:

```
export class TextboxList extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            values: {
                0: ''
            },
        };
        this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
        this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
    }

    handleChange(index, value) {
        this.setState({
            values: {
                ...this.state.values,
                [index]: value
            }
        });
    }

    handleSubmit(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        this.setState({
            values: {
                ...this.state.values,
                [Object.keys(this.state.values).length]: '' // add new empty item to list
            }
        });

    }

    render() {
        return (
            <>
                <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                    { Object.keys(this.state.values).map( (index) => {
                        const value = this.state.values[index];
                        return <div key={ index }>
                            <label>
                                Name:
                                <input
                                    type="text"
                                    value={ value }
                                    onChange={ (event) => this.handleChange( index, event.target.value ) }
                                />
                            </label>
                            <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
                        </div>;
                    })}
                </form>
            </>
        );
    }
}

export default Textbox;
```